# Parse HTML code from database and display it in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm really confused right now..

I have a little form with a textarea and use TinyMCE as a WYSIWYG editor in order to make it easy to write html code. I then submit that code into the database, where I have a column called `content`. An example of that columns content is:

`<p style="text-align:center;>This is a simple <strong>test</strong></p>`

Now, I'm showing a short version of this content in a table-cell and want to display the full content underneath the table, when a user clicks on it.

Therefore, I created a div with `<div id="contentToShow"></div>` first. Then, I have a tablecell, set not to display, that contains the full content and I have another tablecell, that contains the "truncated" data:

```
<td style="display:none;" class="fullContent">{{@myVar.content}}</td>
<td class="clickToShowFullContent">{{substr(@myVar.content,0,50)}}[....]</td>
```

Now I wrote the following jQuery in order to try to display the result in the div:

```
$('.clickToShowFullContent').click(function(){
          var content = $(this).prev().html();
          var $jquery_content = $($.parseHTML(content));
          $('#contentToShow').html($jquery_content);
});
```

Now in theory, this should absolutely make sense.. In the tablecell with the class `fullContent`, there is the full content (as a string). I read the `html` of the table cell and try to assign it to a variable, parsing it to valid HTML by using `$.parseHTML()`. I then try to set the content to the newly created variable.

However, in the end, I only can see the html code instead of the parsed HTML.

What am I doing wrong? Why does it display the code instead of the parsed html?

EDIT:
That's how the `<td>` looks, after the content is inserted

```
<td style="display:none;" class="fullContent">&lt;p&gt;test123&lt;strong&gt;tqetqetqetqetqetqetqqe&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p style="text-align: center;"&gt;&lt;strong&gt;wqeqweqweqweqweeqweqweqweqwe&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;h1 style="text-align: center;"&gt;&lt;em&gt;&lt;strong&gt;asfafsafasfasf&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/em&gt;&lt;/h1&gt;</td>
```

When trying to recreate it in a fiddle, everything is working, you can check it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/otv1fjwk/1/)

Comment: Can u create JSFiddle please

Comment: @Çağrı I tried, but there it works for some reason... has to be something specific from the database, don't know...

Comment: `<p style="text-align:center;>` is missing a closing `"`

Comment: @MarkBaijens that was just demo content, the database contains longer html ( with correct syntax), but got it working now.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I got it working...

It seems like the issue was with the tablecell..

I changed it to the following now:

```
<td style="display:none;" class="fullContent"><input type="hidden" value="{{@myVar.content}}"/></td>
```

and then access it with javascript by using:

```
var content = $(this).prev().children().val();
```

followed by the same method of conversion and now it works... don't know exactly why, but I got it working, guess, that's the main thing :)